# JQuery - Hide/Show with logic

Tags: jquery

I am novice when it comes to JQuery. To put it simply, I have four divs, of class "portlet-topper". Each div has a sibling of the class "portlet-content". This content is hidden, until an instance of portlet-topper is clicked. Once it is clicked, it's sibling content is displayed. I use the following code:

```
$(".portlet-topper").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).siblings(".portlet-content").toggle();
});
```

To clarify before a click:

|----portlet-topper-A----|

|----portlet-topper-B----|

After A is clicked:

|----portlet-topper-A----|

Portlet Content of A

|----portlet-topper-B----|

If I click B, the content of B displays, and A's is left displayed as well. If A has been clicked, I would like the clicking of B to display B while hiding A. How would I go about coding in this logic? I would need this to work for any number of divs, not just two. Essentially, allow only one set of portlet-content to be displayed at once. I figure I'd make explicit calls to show and hide, rather than toggle. Even still, I'm not really sure where to start...

Also, I am using Liferay, so I have little control over the class and id's of each div. I can only manipulate the css or the javascript

Comment: Please, *please*, could this be the *last* time someone *describes* their HTML at us? Really, it's so much easier to just *show* it to us...and, maybe, provide a live demo, at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com), or similar...are all the elements in the same containing element? Or is there a pair, comprised of a `portlet-topper` and a `portlet-content` in each wrapper? Or some *other* structure?

Comment: @DavidThomas what a great comment, by describing html we will see many useless answers that are based on imagination.

Comment: @undefined: ...that's fortunate; I was, really, quite exasperated when I wrote it. *cough* =/

Comment: @DavidThomas oh man, you are right, what you are saying must be a Rule.

Comment: @DavidThomas create an epic rant on Meta. I'll upvote you.

Comment: Well, I made a [meta-tag:feature-request], and fully expect it to be status-declined in short order. But...I really didn't mean my comment, or the question, to *be* a rant. I was just, y'know, grumpier than I should have been. I may wander off, shortly, and have a beer... =/

Comment: okay okay my bad I won't ever use pseudo-html again.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do this:

```
$(".portlet-topper").click(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".portlet-content").hide();
    $(this).siblings(".portlet-content").toggle(); 
});
```

Otherwise, you would never be hiding your contents.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the functionality you are looking for is provided by jQuery UI.

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/22fWm/

Documentation: http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Are there other places in the page where the class 'portlet-content' is used. If not, you could just do this:

```
$('portlet-content').toggle();
```

This will toggle every content area that has that class

Comment: accordion is also a nice jQuery feature, as mentioned by @A.M.K

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the content of the portlet most recently clicked to be displayed, and hide the rest. This is a fail-safe way of doing it without using jQuery UI:

```
$(".portlet-topper").click(function(e) {
    $(".portlet-content").hide();
    $(this).find(".portlet-content").show();
});
```

In case `.portlet-content` is a sibling, not a child of `.portlet-topper`, use `.next()` in stead of `.find()`.

Comment: They're siblings, not descendant. ...probably, my best guess from the question.

Comment: the `.portlet-topper` and `.portlet-content` that is?

Comment: I think so, yeah. I think, (from my best guess), that it should be maybe `$(this).next('.portlet-content').show();`, but, really, this is a guess based on insufficient information.